# How does Oracle implement an SQL query over a VIEW

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a VIEW defined over a base table using an SQL Queries ( SQL **query1** )

Im trying to understand how Querying ( SQL **query2** )  over a view work

1. When I run an SQL over a VIEW, does Oracle first execute query1 to create a temp table and then run query2 over the temp table ?
2. Or does it create a single composite query by combining query1 and query2 in order to give the result

( my query2 has high selectivity if run directly over the base table and a composite query should run much faster than executing query1 first )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. Or does it create a single composite query by combining query1 and query2 in order to give the result

Yes, CBO (oracle cost-based optimizer) expands final query and transforms it and build an execution plan and you can check `final query after transformation` in trace 10053(optimizer trace) or using [DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/expand-sql-text-12cr1)

NB. DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT has appeared in 12.1, but you tagged Oracle 11g, so you need to use `dbms_sql2.expand_sql_text`, an example: https://github.com/xtender/xt_scripts/blob/master/expand_11.sql